# OOP echo $this->title = $part VS echo $par

Tags: php, oop

hi guys im started learning PHP OOP. i have a question. in the example below why do i need to declare var$price,var $title; and use it in
echo $this->title = $par;. in which i can directly echo $par

```
        <?php
        class  Books{
            /* Member variables */
            var $price;
            var $title;
            /* Member functions */
            function setPrice($par){
               $this->price = $par;
            }
            function getPrice(){
               echo $this->price ."<br/>";
            }
            function setTitle($par){
              echo $this->title = $par;
              //echo $par;  what is the difference between the two.

            }
            function getTitle(){
               echo $this->title ." <br/>";
            }
        }
        ?>

        <?php

      $physics = new Books;
       $maths = new Books;
       $chemistry = new Books;
         $physics->setTitle( "Physics for High School" );
       $chemistry->setTitle( "Advanced Chemistry" );
       $maths->setTitle( "Algebra" );

   $physics->setPrice( 10 );
   $chemistry->setPrice( 15 );
   $maths->setPrice( 7 );


    $physics->getTitle();
   $chemistry->getTitle();
   $maths->getTitle();
   $physics->getPrice();
   $chemistry->getPrice();
   $maths->getPrice();
```

Comment: What? What is your question now? Why you have to write: `$this->price = $par;` or `echo $this->price ."<br/>";` or `var $price` ?

Comment: learning oop, don't use `var`. what ever your learning from is very dated

Comment: If you don't do the assignment, `$par` isn't saved in the object.

Comment: The `echo` part is just for debugging.

Comment: my question is why do i need to use $this->price = $par; in which i can directly echo $par. in class books. i used to code using native php thats why i need explanation why i need to use $this-price

Comment: @Nixxx If you have a class property `$price` and a parameter `$price`. How should PHP know which one you mean now? This is why you use `$this` to say php: hey now i'm using the property `$price` from the class and not the parameter or a local variable

Comment: @dagon is it true. that i dont need to declare var $price now in (member variable) oop? @ rizier thanks im started thinking about it. im getting the logic abit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OOP programming is great for extendibility and future proofing. It should be noted that your methods should indicate what they are **expected** to do. In your case, it's a little misleading because `getTitle` implies it will return the name, but instead it echo's it. It should be renamed for `echoName` or something if you intend to keep this functionality. `getTitle` should return it.

To answer your question ("why use a method when I can just access the property") with another question. **What if, in the future, you wanted to make sure every single title was correctly cased?** You would simply replace the `getTitle` method with:

```
public function getTitle() {
     return ucwords(strtolower($this->name));
}
```

This means no other logic within your application needs to change!

Also, a little bit of code review, `var` is a very old syntax. You should be correctly defining the visibility of your properties is much more preferable:

```
protected $title;
protected $price;
```

[Here's a link](http://ideone.com/yTU3PB) to a cleaned up version of how I would implement your example class

Comment: Thanks i actually just added echo in   echo $this->title = $par; part. is it true that as of now i dont need to declare var in OOP? as commented by other users here? like i dont need to declare the var $price and $var title? what replace it? if its true

Comment: `var` is an outdated syntax. You should declare the visiblility of your variables instead. [Here's a link](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php) to the php manual on this topic. Check my modified answer for an example of your class I wrote.

Comment: @Nixxx I also updated the example I made to include the rest of your script (and it even gives the output)

Comment: Thank you so much! for last do you have a link of updated tutorial of PHP OOP? can i have? cause the one i reading is sadly outdated.!! thank you for your help! appreciated!

Comment: oh never mind the link i will read the php manual you provided. thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The point of this is the same as why you use variables in non-OO programming -- so that you can remember a value and recall it later. In this case, you save the value when you call `setTitle()`, and you get it back when you call `getTitle()` later.

You wouldn't normally have an `echo` statement in `setTitle()`. It looks like this is there just to monitor what's going on during development, and you'll take it out before running the program for real.

Answer (score 0):

Because `$par` is a function parameter variable and not a variable stored within the class. If you try to `echo $par;` outside of the function it was passes as a parameter for it won't work

Comment: Clarification - not "_outside of a function_", but rather, "_outside of *the function it was passed as a param to*_"  `$par` is only in scope inside `setPrice()`.